# Pressing F10 causes WM_SETCURSOR message

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, message

I have found in my WinAPI app that WM_SETCURSOR is caused not only by mouse movement, but also by pressing F10 key. How can be this explained and is there way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Like the Alt key, F10 activates the window menu.

Comment: I found that hit test code in this situation is HTCAPTION. How can I distinguish this was caused by mouse of by F10 key?

Comment: Why don't you just follow the rules of the system and respond appropriately to WM_SETCURSOR?

Comment: Why would you want to disable this? It sounds like you are using WM_SETCURSOR to track mouse movements...

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory regarding why the message is sent at all: Showing or activating the window menu could change what is being displayed under the mouse cursor. The mouse cursor now might be wrong with respect to what is underneath (as `WM_SETCURSOR` normally is only generated when the mouse moves). The system knows this and generates a `WM_SETCURSOR` to update the mouse cursor and make it consistent with the changed display.

If this is the case then I doubt that you can disable this behavior.